# phpMyAdmin cannot connect to MySQL but I nothning changed

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

EDIT: My problem was phpMyAdmin cannot connect to MySQL even with correct login. Solved with this https://write.corbpie.com/how-to-fix-mysql-not-starting-in-xampp/

today turned up my computer after a week. Now, when i try to connect to my wordpress web storaged at localhost, it wrotes "An error occurred while connecting to the database server".

So i went to phpMyAdmin and here is a problem with MySQL connection.
It is showed in picture bellow.

[image]

I changed nothing in setting so  I don't know where is a problem and where to find it.

Thanks for response.

BTW: I use XAMPP

Comment: Well, there is not much more we can tell you based on the error messages that something is not OK with your mysql connection - which you already know. You need to make sure that host name or IP adress and port number parameters are correct. Please remember that we cannot tell you what the correct parameters are. I would venture that some other application is listening on the port you think is for mysql.

Comment: The problem is I changed nothing. I tried to look at config.inc.php where are supposed to be name and password, but it's ok because i have not pass and user is root. 
Is it possible to find how I can find if mysql is really running?

Comment: Ok, i solved my problem with this https://write.corbpie.com/how-to-fix-mysql-not-starting-in-xampp/